# How to calculate the cumulative sum taking into account the time dimension in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like (**df**), with millions of rows. It contains information related to sells of different individuals to different countries.

Note: Each row has a different id-prod-d-year:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
               year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2004, 2005, 2004), 
               prod = c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "M", "Z", "Z", "M"), 
               d = c("PER", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "ECU", "ECU", "SPA"), 
               value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10)), 
          class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA,  -10L))
```

I need to know what is the cumsum() value in the previous years for each observation for a given id.
My trial is the following:

```
trial <- df %>% 
  group_by(id, year, d) %>% 
  summarise(valuesum = sum(value)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(cumval = mapply(function(y) cumsum(valuesum[year < y]), year))
```

The result is well calculated. However, it seems that mapply is not adequate in this case, as cumval variable is not in the proper format. I just need to have the last value provided inside each element of cumval.

Any clue?

------ EDIT ------
The desired outcome is the following:

```
trial <- structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
                           "B"), year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2004, 2004, 
                                          2005), d = c("PER", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "ECU", 
                                                       "SPA", "ECU"), valuesum = c(1, 2, 7, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9), cumval = c(0, 
                                                                                                                           0, 3, 10, 15, 21, 0, 0, 18)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your initial pipeline does what you want, you can add the following to your pipeline:

```
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(cumval = ifelse(length(cumval)==0, 0, rev(cumval)[1]))
```

As in :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id, year, d) %>% 
  summarise(valuesum = sum(value)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(cumval = mapply(function(y) cumsum(valuesum[year < y]), year)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(cumval = ifelse(length(cumval)==0, 0, rev(cumval)[1]))
```

Output:

```
  id     year d     valuesum cumval
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A      2000 PER          1      0
2 A      2000 USA          2      0
3 A      2001 USA          7      3
4 A      2002 USA          5     10
5 A      2003 USA          6     15
6 A      2007 USA          7     21
7 B      2004 ECU          8      0
8 B      2004 SPA         10      0
9 B      2005 ECU          9     18
```

However, the above will be extremely slow.  You may find moving to `data.table` is the way to go here:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
result = df[, .(value=sum(value)), .(id,year,d)] %>% 
  .[order(year), `:=`(yr=min(year), cval=shift(cumsum(value))), id] %>% 
  .[yr==year, cval:=0] %>% 
  .[order(year)] %>% 
  .[, yr:=NULL]
```

Output:

```
   id year   d value cval
1:  A 2000 PER     1    0
2:  A 2000 USA     2    0
3:  A 2001 USA     7    3
4:  A 2002 USA     5   10
5:  A 2003 USA     6   15
6:  A 2007 USA     7   21
7:  B 2004 ECU     8    0
8:  B 2004 SPA    10    0
9:  B 2005 ECU     9   18
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need to complete my code. Thank you! An integrated way to convert NAs into 0s?

Comment: actually, if you  have millions of rows, I STRONGLY suggest you move to data.table - see edit (which also gives you your zeros), and avoids the much slower dplyr `group_by`..